# Google Chrome - Text background makes line

Tags: css, google-chrome, background

I tried to have a live background on my text which is the header on my website and I use `-webkit-text-fill-color`,.....

**But after doing this, I saw some invisible lines that appeared on the page.**

This problem just appears in **Google Chrome** and I don't know what to do.

I am using Google Chrome Version 85.0.4183.83 (Official Build) (64-bit).

I don't have this problem using Firefox or other browsers.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show some code? [mre] would be nice.

Comment: it's in picture, in right side bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS properties aren’t in the order they need to be for this effect.

First fill color, then clip, then background, then fallback color:

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
-webkit-background-clip: text;
background: ...;
color: ...;
```

Comment: does it need color? i mean the color of the text is transparent, why should i specify color?
anyway thanks i going to try that out!

Comment: Only as a fallback for older browsers. You can leave it out.